# How does jquery works in nested html pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have one parent html page and I am loading another html page into parent's div using `.load()` function of jquery. There are two separate `.js` files for each parent and child page. when I run child page independently then I am able to see all the validations working fine. 
But when I am loading that page into parent then JavaScript is not working fine. 
when I debug the code, it is showing the error as follows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined

Please let me know when we embed one page into another then how exactly jquery works in that case?

Comment: Show how you define `addMethod` function and describe where you include this js files

Comment: It just means that 'addMethod' which is part of jquery validate is not accessible. Share your code.

Comment: thank u all for the response. for now, i tried adding all html part in one single file and it worked. but please let me know what is the preferred option , to write everything in single file or to have multiple files? thanks in advance.